# Writing intelligent replacement rules for symbols

Tags: replacement

I am learning about quaternions right now, and I wanted to play around with 
some concepts I am learning.

e.g. take rotation of a point about an axis with specified angle.

```
th = 3.4;
v  = Sqrt[1/3.0]*(i + j + k)
q    = Cos[th] + Sin[th]*v;
qinv =  Cos[th] - Sin[th]*v;

p = 2*i + 3*j + 4*k;

r = q * p *qinv // Expand
r = r//.{ i*i->-1, j*j->-1,k*k->-1,
           i*j->k , j*i->-k,
           j*k->i,  k*j->-i,
           k*i->j,  i*k->-j}
```

Here I want to rotate the point *p* in three dimensions by the angle *th*
with the axis given by the unit vector *v*.

So for that I basically just need to use replacement rules like  did above.

The result I get is

```
0.391808 + 2.26121 i - 0.0435342 i^3 + 3.1959 j - 0.0653013 j^3 + 
 4.1306 k - 0.0870683 k^3
```

How do I tell Mathematica to replace **'i^3'** etc. by **'-i'**?  I would have thought Mathematica would be smart enough to use my 'i^2=-1' rule to 
figure this out.

Generalizing this question, if I am manipulating symbols (not just quaternions)
how do I specify replacements so that the final answer is as 'simple' as possible?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13674/245)

Comment: also in Mathematica  i*j and j*i are the same. So when you write a rule for i*j and a different rule for j*i, then Mathematica will use only one, depending on the full form. Look at `FullForm[i*j]` and `FullForm[j*i]`, they are the same.  But for `i^3` to `-i` part, try this rule: `p1 = Power[m_, n_] :> If[n > 2, -m^(n - 2), -m];` then do `i^3//.p1`

Comment: @smilingbuddha you might want to check out the [Quaternions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Quaternions/guide/QuaternionsPackage.html) package in Mathematica.

Answer (score 5):

For this problem, I wouldn't use a rule-based approach to realize the algebraic relations. Instead, if you don't want to load the [`Quaternions` package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Quaternions/tutorial/Quaternions.html), the most robust way to implement quaternions is using their matrix basis representation, see e.g. [this Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quaternion.html) post.

Essentially, the basis vectors can be represented as multiples of the Pauli matrices, so I just modified [my recent answer on the Pauli algebra](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31484/245) to make it work in this case:

For simplicity, I use the symbols `K[0]` for `1`, `K[1]` for `i`, `K[2]` for `j` and `K[3]` instead of `k` because the programming is easier when using indices for the four components. Here is a function that takes a quaternion expression in the component notation and simplifies it using the matrix representation. The multiplication between quaternion components is always required to be written as a `Dot` product because the underlying non-commutative algebra is realized with matrices:

```
Clear[quaternionReduce]
quaternionReduce[a_] := Module[{
   x,
   symbolicQIndices,
   expression,
   component = ({1, I, I, I} PauliMatrix[{0, 3, 2, 1}])
   },
  x = Array[\[FormalX], 4];
  symbolicQIndices = 
   DeleteDuplicates[Cases[a, K[i_Symbol] :> i, Infinity]];
  expression = 
   Array[K, 4, 
     0].(x /. 
      First[Solve[
        x.component == a /. 
         K[i_] :> 
          Sum[KroneckerDelta[i, k] component[[k + 1]], {k, 0, 3}], 
        x]]);
  FullSimplify[expression, 
   Assumptions -> 
    Map[# \[Element] Integers && 1 <= # <= 3 &, symbolicQIndices]]]
```

Here are some examples for doing algebra with this function:

```
quaternionReduce[K[1].K[2]]

(* ==> K[3] *)

quaternionReduce[K[2].K[1]]

(* ==> -K[3] *)

quaternionReduce[K[1].K[2].K[3]]

(* ==> -K[0] *)

quaternionReduce[MatrixPower[K[1], 3]]

(* ==> -K[1] *)

quaternionReduce[MatrixPower[(K[0] + K[1]), 2]]

(* ==> 2 K[1] *)
```

The `K[0]` above is the real unit `1`, as mentioned above. In principle you could make the input and output fancier (i.e., more traditional symbols), but I wanted to keep the programming effort small.

The last two relations address the problem that led to the hang-up in your question. Here, powers are realized using `MatrixPower` and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Replacement rules, at least in a direct form, are frequently not the right choice for mathematical manipulation because they are *structural* tools.

In this case `/. {i^3 -> -i}` works as expected, because that matches the *structure* of the expression.  You will have to write a rule that matches the structure and then performs your transformation if you want it to work with various powers of `i`.  For example:

```
expr /. i^x_ /; x >= 2 :> (-1) i^(x - 2)
```

> 0.391808 + 2.30474 i + 3.1959 j - 0.0653013 j^3 + 4.1306 k - 0.0870683 k^3

Comment: This is part of the answer. However, the rules also require non-commuting operations, so even the starting point using `Power` or `Times` here isn't actually correct for the desired application.

Comment: @Jens Okay, I await your posting the correct answer. :-)